# After creating new recipe the list updates but the UI doesn't unless refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am making a MERN APP and I have an issue where onSaveRecipe the recipes is being saved, the list updates and the UI displays a new component, but the component is empty, null. So I have to refresh the page to see the list updated with all recipes. Same happens when I delete. I need to refresh the page to see that the recipe has been removed from the list.

Here is my code:
Fetching and creating recipe from server:

```
export const fetchRecipes = createAsyncThunk(
  "recipes/fetchRecipes",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
      try {
         const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}recipes`);
         return response.data;
      } catch (er) {
          return rejectWithValue(er.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

export const createRecipe = createAsyncThunk(
    "recipes/createRecipe",
    async (recipe) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${baseURL}recipes`, recipe);
        return response.data;
    } catch (er) {
        console.log(er.response.data.message);
    }
  }
); 
const recipesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "recipes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchRecipes.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = "loading";
        })
        .addCase(fetchRecipes.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = "succeeded";
            state.recipes = state.recipes.concat(action.payload);
        })
        .addCase(fetchRecipes.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = "failed";
            state.error = action.error.message;
        }) 
}});
```

Displaying all recipes in a list:

```
const SingleRecipe = ({ recipe }) => {
  return (
    <article className={styles["recipe-excerpt"]} key={recipe._id + recipe}>
      <h3>{recipe.title}</h3>
      <div className={styles["square"]}>
        <img src={recipe.image} />
      </div>
      <TimeAgo timestamp={recipe.createdAtDate} />
      <Link to={`recipes/${recipe._id}`}>See more</Link>
    </article>
  );
};

const RecipesList = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const recipes = useSelector(selectAllRecipes);
    const shouldDispatch = useRef(true);
    const recipeStatus = useSelector((state) => state.recipes.status);
    const error = useSelector((state) => state.recipes.error);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (recipeStatus === "idle" && shouldDispatch.current) {
        dispatch(fetchRecipes());
        shouldDispatch.current = false;
      }
    }, [recipeStatus, dispatch]);

    let content;

    if (recipes.status === "loading") {
      content = <Loader text="Loading..." />;
    } else if (recipeStatus === "succeeded") {
      const orderedRecipes = recipes
        .slice()
        .sort((a, b) =>
          b.createdAtDate ? b.createdAtDate.localeCompare(a.createdAtDate) : ""
        );

      content = orderedRecipes.map((recipe) => (
        <SingleRecipe key={recipe._id+recipe.title} recipe={recipe} />
      ));
    } else if (recipeStatus === "failed") {
      content = <div>{error}</div>;
    }


    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Recipes</h2>
        <div className={styles["recipes-list__container"]}>{content}</div>
      </section>
    );
  };
```

And finally the function of saving new recipe

```
const canSave =
    [title, content, ingridients, category].every(Boolean) && requestStatus === "idle";

  const onSaveRecipeClicked = async () => {
    if (canSave) {
      try {
        setRequestStatus("pending");
        await dispatch(
          createRecipe({ title, content, ingridients, image, category })
        )
        setTitle("");
        setContent("");
        setImage("");
        setCategory("");
        setIngridients([{ amount: "", ingridientName: "" }]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to save the post: ", error);
      } finally {
        setRequestStatus("idle");
      }
    }
  };
```

While debugging the prop of the newly added recipe before refresh looks like that [The props recipe has first response and inside response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgrII.png)

And the others recipes props look like that: [The props has recipe and the data inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDm5r.png)

[That's how the list of recipes looks after saving new recipe and before refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V46ZF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'content' variable is not recomputing after state changes. You can compute it inside 'useMemo'.
Or you can try to move content to the different component, so it will be more readable.

```
const RecipesContent = (recipes, recipeStatus) => {
  if (recipes.status === "loading") {
    return <Loader text="Loading..." />;
  }

  if (recipeStatus === "failed") {
    return <div>{error}</div>;
  }

  const orderedRecipes = recipes
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) =>
      b.createdAtDate ? b.createdAtDate.localeCompare(a.createdAtDate) : ""
    );

  return orderedRecipes.map((recipe) => (
    <SingleRecipe key={recipe._id + recipe.title} recipe={recipe} />
  ));
};

const RecipesList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const recipes = useSelector(selectAllRecipes);
  const shouldDispatch = useRef(true);
  const recipeStatus = useSelector((state) => state.recipes.status);
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.recipes.error);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (recipeStatus === "idle" && shouldDispatch.current) {
      dispatch(fetchRecipes());
      shouldDispatch.current = false;
    }
  }, [recipeStatus, dispatch]);

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Recipes</h2>
      <div className={styles["recipes-list__container"]}>
        <RecipesContent recipes={recipes} recipeStatus={recipeStatus} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: I did remove the 'content' variable and moved to different component but the issue still remains the same. How can I compute it inside useMemo hook? I tried to use this hook for 'orderedRecipes = useMemo(() => {recipes.recipes
        .slice()
        .sort((a, b) =>
          b.createdAtDate ? b.createdAtDate.localeCompare(a.createdAtDate) : ""
        )}, [recipes.recipes]) but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have the reducer function for 'createRecipe' action?

Comment: I have the extraReducer: ".addCase(createRecipe.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(createRecipe.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        state.recipes = [...state.recipes, action.payload];
      })
      .addCase(createRecipe.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })"

Comment: Maybe check what exactly comes from createRecipe action in extra reducer. 
Try to console action.payload

Comment: {response: {…}}
response: 
category: 
"ccc"
content: 
"cc"
createdAtDate: 
"2024-01-22T16:42:10.817Z"
ingridients: 
[{…}]
title: 
"19"
__v: 
0
_id: 
"65ae9ae2691e056a5a39ceff"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object
[[Prototype]]: 
Object  The action.payload seems fine to me

Comment: Looks like you should update state with action.payload.response instead of action payload?